# Script execute script without executing permission

Tags: linux, perl

I have perl script which has no execute permission (only rw) when I try to run this script "./script.pl" I get "Permission denied" and it is clear for me. But when I run this script using "perl -e script.pl" it works and script is executed though its own permission.

Could somebody explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: What would be strange is if it behaved in any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the command

> perl script.pl

the perl executable is executed from the shell (with some of the exec() system calls). The file /usr/bin/perl will then need +x because every file that is executed with exec() needs that. Perl will run with the argument script.pl and perl is programmed to open a file that is given to it on the command line and process the content.

When you run the file in this way

> ./script.pl

the shell will run the file script.pl directly by using some of the exec() system calls and then script.pl is the file that will need +x.

In other words, if you want to run the file like ./script.pl, you need to

> chmod +x script.pl

You will also need a "shebang" as first line of your script, telling which command you want to use to run it. It will look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Comment: Hi Anders,                                                                   Thanks for reply, but I still don't understand something. I made similar case. I created script test1 with execute permission which execute script test2 (without x). This time script test2 is not being executed.                                                          test@note ~/Desktop $ ls -l test*
-rwxr--r-- 1 test test 20 kwi 23 22:40 test1
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 26 kwi 23 22:41 test2
test@note ~/Desktop $ ./test1 
./test1: line 3: ./test2: Permission denied

Comment: If you run test2 like ./test2, you will need +x on test2, regardless if you run it from the command line or from another script. The shell will in fact make no difference between those (I assume test1 is a shell script here).

Comment: You can always have the line bash test2 in the script test1, and then +x is not needed in test2. A more lightweight version is sh test2. Also, put the suffix .sh on shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you are trying to execute the script.

In the second case (if we ignore the `-e`) you are trying to execute perl, and are telling it to run the code in the file script.pl.

(The `-e` causes it to try to run the literal text `script.pl` as Perl code)